# Macos with Virtualbox and Wireshark on LAN network

Tags: kali-linux, macos, wireshark

I have a virtual machine on a macos, within that virtual machine I have a Debian distribution and I want to use Wireshark to capture all the traffic from the lan network, from virtualbox. I have configured the network adapter as:

- "Bridge adapter"
- The name goes to en0 (wifi)
- Promiscuous mode allows everything.

I have tried with all possible connections, Wireshark captures the Kali Linux traffic, but not from Macos and not from the local network (such as a telephone). Does anyone know what could be happening? Has it happened to anyone else?

More info:
The virtual machine are in the same network that the guest but i can't ping them
Config
[image]

Comment: Are you bridging a wifi adapter? If so, that's almost certainly the problem - you usually can't do that

Comment: Hi! I'm not using any wifi adapter, from VirtualBox the word Wireless appears (I correct by wifi by wireless) sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridged adaptors don't send your virtual machine all traffic.  They intercept traffic destined for your VM and re-route it.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

> Oracle VM VirtualBox uses a device driver on your host system that filters data from your physical network adapter. This driver is therefore called a net filter driver. This enables Oracle VM VirtualBox to intercept data from the physical network and inject data into it, effectively creating a new network interface in software. When a guest is using such a new software interface, it looks to the host system as though the guest were physically connected to the interface using a network cable.

Switches do not send every packet to every machine, they only send the packet to it's recipient based on the packet's recipient MAC address.  (This rule is a little different for WiFi).

The VM's bridge adaptor works in a similar way; the bridge device of your VM will have it's own MAC address and to your router it will appear that there are two devices on one wire.  On the host os (OS X in your case), these are further filtered, so that the VM only receives packets addressed to the VM.

For this kind of snooping there needs to be some form of attack such as [ARP poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing).